# Mysql query with left join and show result in html table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two mysql tables "films" and "showtime", variables for query '$place_id=2' and '$date=2013-11-22' as example.

showtime table have colomns 'id', 'film_id', 'place_id', 'hall_id', 'time', 'date';

films table have colomns 'id', 'title';

I wrote query with left join, because one query is better than a several as I think:

```
SELECT `showtime`.`id`, `showtime`.`film_id`, `showtime`.`place_id`,
`showtime`.`hall_id`, `showtime`.`time`, `showtime`.`date`, `films`.`id`, 
`films`.`title` FROM (`showtime`)
LEFT JOIN `films` ON `films`.`id` = `showtime`.`film_id`
WHERE `showtime`.`date` = '2013-11-22' AND `showtime`.`place_id` = '2'
ORDER BY `films`.`title` asc, `showtime`.`time` asc
```

as a result of this query I got this:

```
print_r($result):

Array (
[0] => stdClass Object (
[id] => 4 [film_id] => 4 [place_id] => 2 [hall_id] => 2 [time] => 09:00:00
[date] => 2013-11-22 [title] => Hunger Games 2 )
[1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [film_id] => 4 [place_id] => 2 [hall_id] => 2
[time] => 22:30:00 [date] => 2013-11-22 [title] => Hunger Games 2 )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [film_id] => 1 [place_id] => 2 [hall_id] => 2
[time] => 09:00:00 [date] => 2013-11-22 [title] => Thor 2 )
[3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [film_id] => 1 [place_id] => 2 [hall_id] => 2
[time] => 11:00:00 [date] => 2013-11-22 [title] => Thor 2 ) )
```

With using default foreach I have got table like this:

```
Title          | Time
__________________________________
Hunger games 2 | 09:00:00
__________________________________
Hunger games 2 | 22:30:00
__________________________________
Thor 2         | 09:00:00
__________________________________
Thor 2         | 11:00:00
```

How I can group results by title in php to get html table like this:

```
Title          | Time
__________________________________
Hunger games 2 | 09:00:00 22:30:00
__________________________________
Thor 2         | 09:00:00 11:00:00
```

Any suggestions? May be I chose wrong approach with query? What is the better way to parse result from complex join queries? Thank you!

Comment: Are all the fields you select used? Or is the query only to create the table?

Comment: It's just simple example to understand how I can group results in join queries. And I got right answer - group_concat function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the query is only used to produce the table you can use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT `films`.`title` 
GROUP_CONCAT(`showtime`.`time`) AS filmtime
FROM (`showtime`)
LEFT JOIN `films` ON `films`.`id` = `showtime`.`film_id`
WHERE `showtime`.`date` = '2013-11-22' AND `showtime`.`place_id` = '2'
GROUP BY films.id
ORDER BY `films`.`title` asc, `showtime`.`time` asc
```

Will produce a result similar to your second table. You can use this in your current loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql GROUP_CONCAT function :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat